# difference in inserting data using select from dual

Tags: oracle

what is the difference with both query ? are they same ? do they give the same results ? I saw them in a script and I wonder if there is a difference.

```
Query 1 :
insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) values ( 1 , 'st' , 'ov');


Query 2 :
insert into tab1 ( id , name , last ) select 1 , 'st' , 'ov' from dual;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in this case.

Using a `select ... from dual` for the insert can be useful in some cases (when using data from another table for example, an `union`, etc.), but in this case it doesn't add anything to the usual `insert into`.

Consider this being useful:

```
insert
into   table_x
( col1
)
select 'a'
from   dual
union
all
select 'b'
from   dual
;
```

Comment: Also useful if you want to insert multiple rows with values generated from a `connect by`; or from a `union all` of several `select ... from dual` in place of separate `insert` statements. (Your 'using data from another table' is a bit confusing though; you wouldn't generally use that *and* `from dual`?)

Comment: yes , joinning with an inner select . so I understand from your answer it is same result. thanks @patrick